# Comparing write stream with read stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

While testing responses of a server, I'd like to see that it sends a specific file/asset. To check, if the result is as expected, the workflow for me is currently:

1. Write response data into buffer
2. Read the static asset into another buffer
3. Compare both buffers

Is there a way to compare the data "on-the-fly" without having to write everything into buffers (or files)?

I'm thinking of implementing a transform stream that yields `true` or `false` in the end, but I guess there exists something like that already and I just couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone implemented it as a node module already: [stream-equal](https://github.com/fent/node-stream-equal)